# Show the hermitian of two operators is...

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $(\hat Q \hat R)^\dagger = (\hat R)^\dagger(\hat Q)^\dagger$

It is necessary to show this equality using Dirac notation, but i am a little confused:

Attemp 1 (Wrong):

$\langle f|QR|g \rangle = (\langle f|QR\rangle)|g \rangle =\langle Q^\dagger|fR|g\rangle = \langle Q^\dagger(\langle fR|g\rangle) = \langle Q^\dagger R^\dagger|f|g\rangle$

Attempt 2 (Right):

$\langle f|QR|g \rangle = (\langle f|QR\rangle)|g \rangle = \langle Q^\dagger|fR|g\rangle = \langle (Q^\dagger|f)R|g\rangle = \langle R^\dagger Q^\dagger |f|g\rangle$

My question is why is the first attempt wrong, can't we say that $\langle f|z|g \rangle = \langle f| ( \langle z|g \rangle) = (\langle f|z \rangle)|g \rangle $ ? So where did i make the mistake?

Comment: Attempt 2 is just as bad as Attempt 1. Both of them pretend that talking about $|A\rangle$ and $\langle A|$ where $A$ is a linear operator somehow makes sense. In general no such kets or bras are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does work is this:
By definition, $A^\dagger$ is the linear operator such that for all kets $|f\rangle, |g\rangle$, $$\langle g|A^\dagger|f\rangle = \overline{\langle f|A|g\rangle}$$

(the complex conjugate - generally Dirac notation is used for complex Hilbert spaces, as those are necessary for Quantum theory). Therefore, for each $g$, $\langle g|A^\dagger$ is the bra associated with the ket $A|g\rangle$. And for each $f$, $\langle f|A$ is the bra associated with the ket $A^\dagger|f\rangle$.

Now, recalling that $\langle u|v\rangle = \overline{\langle v|u\rangle}$ and that the bra $\langle u|A^\dagger$ and ket $ A|u\rangle$ are associates,

$$\langle f|QR|g\rangle = (\langle f|Q)\,(R|g\rangle) = \overline{(\langle g|R^\dagger)\,(Q^\dagger|f\rangle)}=\overline{\langle g|R^\dagger Q^\dagger|f\rangle}$$
which by the definition means $$(QR)^\dagger = R^\dagger Q^\dagger$$

Now it is possible that given an operator $A$, someone may choose to use "$\langle uA|$" to represent the bra $\langle u|A$, and use "$|Au\rangle$" to represent the ket $A|u\rangle$. This is because what is inside the bra and ket notations is merely a label. As long as the interpretation of the label is understood so that one can determine the particular bra or ket it means, this is acceptable. And that is the case with $\langle uA| \equiv \langle u|A$ and $|Au\rangle\equiv A|u\rangle$.

Using this notational shorthand, the calculation above becomes

$$\langle f|QR|g\rangle = \langle fQ|Rg\rangle = \overline{\langle gR^\dagger|Q^\dagger f\rangle}=\overline{\langle g|R^\dagger Q^\dagger|f\rangle}$$

which is close to what you wrote. But note the difference. This uses the notations $\langle fQ|, |Rg\rangle, \langle gR^\dagger|, |Q^\dagger f\rangle$, each of which has been defined to represent a particular bra or ket. Your version uses notations $|QR\rangle, \langle Q^\dagger|, \langle R^\dagger Q^\dagger|$ which lack any means of tying them to particular bras or kets.

I have to assume that $\langle(Q^\dagger|f)R|g\rangle$ should have been $(\langle Q^\dagger|f)R|g\rangle$, but even with that correction you use $f$ outside of the bra. What does that mean? $f$ is merely a *label* used to identify the particular bra and ket pair $\langle f|$ and $|f\rangle$. It is not an operator that can act on bras or kets.